# Touch events clicks whats behind it phonegap zepto

Tags: android, html, cordova, zepto

I created a drawer using HTML5 that has position fixed with a z-index greater than what's behind it (similar to the Gmail android native app). When it is toggled(opened), and after clicking any link, it clicks what's behind it. I am using zepto touch, and "touchend" as event type.
Any clue how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
$(elem).on("touchend", function() {
    ... do your stuff ...
    document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

You could also try setting `pointer-events: none;` with CSS to elements that are behind the menu. And then set it back to "auto", when drawer is closed.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the "pointer-events: none;" and it worked no need for the "document.activeElement.blur();" and it worked!